Abstracting a real hardware and simulated device with the same interface in Python
I am looking for a more idiomatic or concise OOP pattern to implement the equivalent of the following.
Interface and implementations
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import override

class Device:
    """Main interface that hides whether the device is a real hardware device or
    a simulated device.
    """

    def __init__(self, ip_address: str, port: int, simulated: bool) -> None:
        if simulated:
            self.__session = DeviceSimulated()
        else:
            self.__session = DeviceHardware(ip_address, port)

    def initialize(self) -> None: self.__session.initialize()

    def close(self) -> None: self.__session.close()

    def turn_on(self) -> None: self.__session.turn_on()

    def turn_off(self) -> None: self.__session.turn_off()

class DeviceHardware(Device):
    def __init__(self, ip_address: str, port: int) -> None:
        self._ip_address = ip_address
        self._port = port

    @override
    def initialize(self) -> None:
        print(f"DeviceHardware initialized with IP: {self._ip_address} and Port: {self._port}")

    @override
    def close(self) -> None: print("DeviceHardware closed")

    @override
    def turn_on(self) -> None: print("DeviceHardware turned on")

    @override
    def turn_off(self) -> None: print("DeviceHardware turned off")


class DeviceSimulated(Device):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Nothing to initialized for the simulated device
        pass

    @override
    def initialize(self) -> None: print(f"DeviceSimulated initialized")

    @override
    def close(self) -> None: print("DeviceSimulated closed")

    @override
    def turn_on(self) -> None: print("DeviceSimulated turned on")

    @override
    def turn_off(self) -> None: print("DeviceSimulated turned off")

Client usage
This would be used by a client like this.
# Simulated case
device = Device(ip_address="192.168.1.10", port=123, simulated=True)
device.initalize()
device.turn_on()
device.turn_off()
device.close()

# Real hardware case
device = Device(ip_address="192.168.1.10", port=123, simulated=False)
device.initalize()
device.turn_on()
device.turn_off()
device.close()

Question
Basically, the point is that I present a unified interface to users, such that all they need to be concerned with is toggling the simulated argument. And similarly, I present a shared unified interface for the simulated and real hardware device implementations of the interface.
Is there a better Python and/or OOP way to handle this to satisfy these two constraints? This works, is simple, and is straightforward, but it is a little verbose perhaps. So while there may be more elegant solutions, I am particularly interested in those that require even less code and boilerplate.
I've done this in a different language, however, the objects were value-based and not referenced based, so it was done differently. As it stands here in Python, it's a little bit like the State Pattern, in that the Device changes its "state" based upon the simulated argument, with each method deferring down to the specific, actual "state" of the class.

There are more approaches to making an interface and its implementation. You can see some of the possibilities here: How do I implement interfaces in python?.
Your OOP design has some problems:

You have cyclic dependency: Device knows about DeviceSimulated (in the constructor) and DeviceSimulated knows about Device ("implements" its). To solve this problem you should remove the constructor in the Device. Automatically you will not violate the Open-Closed Principle in Device, if you will create new subtype of Device.
In the client usage, your client knows about implementation: device = Device(ip_address="192.168.1.10", port=123, simulated=True) in the simulated=True. The client should use the interface Device and should not know about implementation. To solve the problem a client code should use an "pure" interface Device. Instantiation implementation should be in a different part of the program (for example, in tests you will instantiate DeviceSimulated).


Thanks for taking a look. For (1), there is a conceptual cyclic dependency but no actual one as long as the child classes do not call their super's init method, which would lead to exhausting the recursion stack. In this case, there will only ever be two child classes: one for simulation and the other for actual hardware. For (2), the simulated argument isn't exposing any implementation. It is exposing exactly what it is doing, in that the client may request that the class is internally simulated or uses hardware. It's a feature that Device provides, which doesn't expose how it does so.

I understand mixins, interfaces, etc., but I'm still not aware of how to make this more concise and simple, besides making the boilerplate go away via metaprogramming. This is effectively the state pattern, which is a viable pattern and often does have a circular dependence between the context and state, though it is rarely drawn in the class diagrams.

You have an actual cycle - (Device) in your subclasses. An idea of polymorphism in write the same code and use it with different implementations, but you have different client code: line device = Device(…). I recommend to you start from design, try to write your snippet on java, using keywords: interface and implements, after that  move in to python, and after think how to optimize the code.

I meant conceptual in the sense of it being of no consequence. Yes, Device "has-a" DeviceHardware or DeviceSimulated, DeviceHardware "is-a" Device, and DeviceSimulated "is-a" Device, but what is actually wrong with it? Yes, cycles are generally not great, but this is well-contained.

Again, the client code is different only in the sense of it having different argument parameters, but that happens all the time. Just because simulated selects either a real or simulated device doesn't mean it exposes implementation. It doesn't. It is the client itself that wants to determine whether a device tries to connect to a real device or a simulated one.

Do you have a suggested code architecture/example? I'm familiar with OOP from F#, which has actual abstract classes and interfaces. I'd obviously do things differently there.
